# Post more than one value using checkboxes and a single submit button

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying post 3 different values of check box using this code. If I post different values, the same value is getting posted into 3 of them.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="s_status[]" value="absent" /></td>
<input type="checkbox" name="s_status[]" value="present" /></td>
<input type="checkbox" name="s_status[]" value="leave" /></td>
```

```
<?php
require 'conn/Session.php';
require 'conn/MySQL.php';
require_once("includes/generalFunction.php");
require_once("classes/class.SiteManager.php");
$dbcon =  new MySQL();
$siteObj =  new SiteManager();
require 'conn/checkSession.php';
if($_POST['submit']) 
{
    $content=array("student_id"=>$_POST['student_id'],"parent_id"=>$_POST['parent_id'],"student_name"=>$_POST['student_name'],"s_status"=>$_POST['s_status'],"class"=>$_POST['class'],"section"=>$_POST['section']);
    $content1=array("student_id"=>$_POST['student_id'],"parent_id"=>$_POST['parent_id'],"student_name"=>$_POST['student_name'],"s_status"=>$_POST['s_status'],"class"=>$_POST['class'],"section"=>$_POST['section']);
    $content2=array("student_id"=>$_POST['student_id'],"parent_id"=>$_POST['parent_id'],"student_name"=>$_POST['student_name'],"s_status"=>$_POST['s_status'],"class"=>$_POST['class'],"section"=>$_POST['section']);


    $dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content);
    $dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content1);
    $dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content2);
    $mess="Record created successfully.";
    $url="all_attandence.php?mess=".base64_encode($mess);
    redirectPage($url);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your code. Please check:-

```
require 'conn/Session.php';
require 'conn/MySQL.php';
require_once("includes/generalFunction.php");
require_once("classes/class.SiteManager.php");

$dbcon =  new MySQL();

$siteObj =  new SiteManager();

require 'conn/checkSession.php';

if($_POST['submit']) 
{
    $content=array("student_id"=>$_POST['student_id'],"parent_id"=>$_POST['parent_id'],"student_name"=>$_POST['student_name'],"s_status"=>$_POST['s_status'][0],"class"=>$_POST['class'],"section"=>$_POST['section']);
    $content1=array("student_id"=>$_POST['student_id'],"parent_id"=>$_POST['parent_id'],"student_name"=>$_POST['student_name'],"s_status"=>$_POST['s_status'][1],"class"=>$_POST['class'],"section"=>$_POST['section']);
    $content2=array("student_id"=>$_POST['student_id'],"parent_id"=>$_POST['parent_id'],"student_name"=>$_POST['student_name'],"s_status"=>$_POST['s_status'][2],"class"=>$_POST['class'],"section"=>$_POST['section']);

    $dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content);
    $dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content1);
    $dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content2);
    $mess="Record created successfully.";
    $url="all_attandence.php?mess=".base64_encode($mess);
    redirectPage($url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you retrieve `s_status` on the server side, it's an array. You have to iterate over this array or query it with an index:

```
<?php
require 'conn/Session.php';
require 'conn/MySQL.php';
require_once("includes/generalFunction.php");
require_once("classes/class.SiteManager.php");
$dbcon =  new MySQL();
$siteObj =  new SiteManager();
require 'conn/checkSession.php';
if($_POST['submit']) 
{
    $content=array(
        "student_id"=>$_POST['student_id'],
        "parent_id"=>$_POST['parent_id'],
        "student_name"=>$_POST['student_name'],
        "s_status"=>$_POST['s_status'][0], //First
        "class"=>$_POST['class'],
        "section"=>$_POST['section']
    );
    $content1=array(
        "student_id"=>$_POST['student_id'],
        "parent_id"=>$_POST['parent_id'],
        "student_name"=>$_POST['student_name'],
        "s_status"=>$_POST['s_status'][1], //Second
        "class"=>$_POST['class'],
        "section"=>$_POST['section']
    );
    $content2=array(
        "student_id"=>$_POST['student_id'],
        "parent_id"=>$_POST['parent_id'],
        "student_name"=>$_POST['student_name'],
        "s_status"=>$_POST['s_status'][2], //Third
        "class"=>$_POST['class'],
        "section"=>$_POST['section']
    );


    $dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content);
    $dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content1);
    $dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content2);
    $mess="Record created successfully.";
    $url="all_attandence.php?mess=".base64_encode($mess);
    redirectPage($url);
}
?>
```

As suggested by [David JorHpan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4395287/david-jorhpan), you can optimize your code by eliminating the duplicate code (I'm asssuming here your MySQL class return `true` or `false` depending on the success of the query):

```
<?php
require 'conn/Session.php';
require 'conn/MySQL.php';
require_once("includes/generalFunction.php");
require_once("classes/class.SiteManager.php");
$dbcon =  new MySQL();
$siteObj =  new SiteManager();
require 'conn/checkSession.php';
if($_POST['submit']) 
{
    $success = true;
    foreach ($_POST['s_status'] as $s_status)
    {
        $content=array(
            "student_id"    =>  $_POST['student_id'],
            "parent_id"     =>  $_POST['parent_id'],
            "student_name"  =>  $_POST['student_name'],
            "s_status"      =>  $s_status,
            "class"         =>  $_POST['class'],
            "section"       =>  $_POST['section']
        );
        $success = $dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content) and $success;
    }
    if($success)
    {
        $mess = "Records created successfully.";
    }
    else
    {
        $mess = "Error during the records creation.";
    }
    $url = "all_attandence.php?mess=".base64_encode($mess);
    redirectPage($url);
}
?>
```

### Notice:

I don't know what's inside your `MySQL.php` file but it looks like you pass the `$_POST` values directly to MySQL. I strongly advise you to [use PDO or similar to protect from SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/4074148).

Answer (score 0):

Your current checkbox html is the best for access data in action file ,try query with `foreach`

```
if($_POST['submit']) 
{
$send = false;
foreach ($_POST['s_status'] as $sts) {
    $content= array("student_id"=>$_POST['student_id'],"parent_id"=>$_POST['parent_id'],"student_name"=>$_POST['student_name'],"s_status"=>$sts,"class"=>$_POST['class'],"section"=>$_POST['section']);
    $send   = $dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content);
}
if($send){
$mess="Record created successfully.";
}
else {
$mess = "Error";
}
$url="all_attandence.php?mess=".base64_encode($mess);
redirectPage($url);                        
}
```